# How to find the Build Bundles ID with Appstore Connect APIs

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, testflight, fastlane

Need to get the size of the build using appstore connect API call.
Trying to find the what exactly is the ID mentioned here in the below endpoint.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_file_sizes_for_a_build_bundle

```
GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/buildBundles/{id}/buildBundleFileSizes
```

As per the documentation it is `the opaque resource ID that uniquely identifies the Build Bundles resource.`

Is there any fastlane action to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

#### first

you need get the builds detail from `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_builds`

and the most important is the parameters  `"include": "buildBundles"`

the you can find the response include buildBundleFileSizes links

```
"buildBundleFileSizes": {
                "links": {
                    "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/buildBundles/{buildBundles id}/relationships/buildBundleFileSizes",
                    "related": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/buildBundles/{buildBundles id}/buildBundleFileSizes"
                }
            }
```

#### then

you can visit the links, get the binary size.